# Run automated tests on AWS device farm in incremented ways

Tags: selenium-grid, aws-device-farm

I am evaluating AWS device farm for running mobile web test. These are the steps I am anticipating:

> 1. Create sample tests (Java)
> 2. Package that as zip file
> 3. Go through the AWS device farm console and upload the test zip only
> 4. Manually select the configuration and other things
> 5. Manually execute the test and evaluate results

For thing I need help are:

> a) What if the tests needs some changes, do I need to go through the JAR package creation for every run? Can I run test from my IDE and if everything works fine then only package and upload it on AWS device farm?
>
> b) To do (a) I noticed they have API to simulate step 3-5 to achieve running tests but wondering if there is some easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps you've listed are the correct sequence of tasks that need to be performed to run tests on a device. With AWS Device Farm, you have to perform the extra step of uploading the tests and application to the service. As you stated, every time you change your tests, you will need to rebuild the JAR and upload it. Most customers set up a continuous build/integration pipeline using a tool like Jenkins to perform this task automatically.

If you are running in Android Studio, you can use the [Device Farm Gradle plugin](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/aws-device-farm-gradle-plugin-setting-up.html), which will do the work for you.